# How to achieve functionality akin to an "abstract static" field

Tags: java

I've created an `abstract class` contains a method with an implementation. This method is called by subclasses to populate a list, which should be shared amongst all instances of each individual subclass (like an `abstract static` field which is different and static to each subclass). The issue is: `abstract static` fields do not exist, so how else might I be able to achieve this behaviour?

For context, the implemented method on the `abstract class` is for resolving classes from an unqualified name via the [reflections8](https://github.com/aschoerk/reflections8) package. This method calls an `abstract` method to get the packages to reflect, which just returns a `String[]` (as subclasses will want to search in different packages). This method then generates a `Map<String, Class<?>>` containing a mapping of the name of each reflected class to the `Class`, which is what I would like to share between instances of each specific subclass type (so that it doesn't have to reflect for the same subclass more than once). Ultimately, this method is called by the subclass in order to instantiate a class from its unqualified name.

Please forgive me if this is a rather strange way of doing things; I come from the land of iOS where we don't have package names attached to class names (so I can just call `NSClassFromString("ClassName")` and that's it).

EDIT: Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jacobcxdev/b1a43273d677d360a2bab6937c34b82e) for the current implementation (and check out the comment for a usage example).

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts: if you're wanting your subclasses to have their own respective static fields, it's best to just have those static fields declared in them rather than this `abstract class`.

From what I understand, your `abstract class` is really just a placeholder for this one implemented method. Do any of your subclasses override anything from the parent? If not, maybe it doesn't need to be an abstract class.

Plus, does your `abstract class` need any state? Because if not, you might be better off with this: change your `abstract class` to be a `static class`, and your implemented method be a `static` method, which accepts an "ClassName" argument. Then in your subclasses you can just directly call the method with your subclass' static fields using something akin to `MyStaticClass. NSClassFromString(subclassStaticField);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To give a little more context, the `abstract class` is used for storing an enum, two instance fields, and an `abstract` instance method. I've copy-pasted the `abstract class` along with an example subclass into [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jacobcxdev/b1a43273d677d360a2bab6937c34b82e) for you (check out the comment for a usage example). I think I'm trying to use the `abstract class` like a Swift protocol, but I can see that things work a little differently in Java. Based on the gist, do you think the `abstract class` is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent for `abstract static` for fields:

- An instance field cannot be `abstract`.  It really makes no sense.  `abstract` means we are deferring some of the details to a subclass. But for an instance field there is nothing that *it makes sense* to defer.
- A `static` field is not inherited anyway, so there is no way one could be used polymorphically.  `static` fields with the same name in different classes are distinct variables.

You can (of course) use reflection to test if a field (static or instance) *has been declared* ... but that's not what `abstract` means in Java.

Solution:

- If you want an instance field to exist in all of the subclasses of an `abstract` class, declare it as a regular field in the `abstract` class.
- If you want a `static` field to exist in all subclasses, you have no choice but to explicitly declare it in each subclass.  You won't be able to use it / them polymorphically.

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose, the functionality I'm looking for might not be supported natively in Java.